# ARkit unity project, video playback stops. iOS 11.2.5 with error: Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=102 "Required sensor failed."

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

camera playback stops after a few seconds of scanning, but other things(like touches) is alright. It starts after device update to 11.2.5 (we think so). In xcode I found this exception:

> 2018-02-06 12:38:30.324438+0300 arkitscene[5138:1590376] [Session]
>   Session (0x1100ea340): did fail with error: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=102 "Required sensor failed."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=A sensor failed to deliver the
>   required input., NSUnderlyingError=0x1c524f960 {Error
>   Domain=CMErrorDomain Code=102 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Make sure that the application has the
>   required privacy settings., NSLocalizedDescription=Required sensor
>   failed.}

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by changing Start Alignment at ARCameraManager in unity editor from Unity AR Alignment Gravity and Heading to Unity AR Alignment Gravity.